# How to calculate hamming distance for more than 2 inputs

Tags: math, distance, calculus

[here the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c432i.png)

```
1001110
1110101
1010011
0011011
```

How can calculate hamming distance for this example. Can you explain pls for more than 2 inputs.

Comment: How would it make sense to have a distance between more than 2 points?

Comment: Two values have one hamming distance. Four values have six hamming distances, calculate all of them. (I am ignoring picture of text, yes. Because it shows a different question than you ask.)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the minimum Hamming distance?  The minimum Hamming distance of a code is the smallest Hamming distance between a pair of codewords.  In your example code, which contains four codewords, the two closest codewords are the last two codewords, and they differ in exactly two positions. Hence, the minimum Hamming distance of this code is 2.

Comment: İ guess its minimum hamming distance , thanks for helps.